# React JS. Наследование или делегирование

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Пишу фронтэнд для сайта с использованием React JS, у меня есть в шаблоне 2 кнопки с виду ничем не отличающиеся, создал для этой кнопки компонент, рендерится, все отлично.

Но, мне нужно чтобы у этих двух кнопок было разное поведение при клике, как лучше задавать это поведение? Каким-то образом отнаследовать два компонента? Делегировать другой компонент? Или есть какая-то система декорирования? Примеси? Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше быть :)

Comment: Наследоваться не надо. Реакт проповедует композицию сейчас. А с самого начала миксины проповедовал, но сейчас это уже не модно.
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.m8cru680o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так...

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

class AwesomeButton extends React.Component {
  handleChange() {
    // awesom logic
  }

  render() {
    // передали все свойства и немного поменяли логику...
    return <Button {...this.props} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: хм, это не работает, мне кажется композицию можно приметь только для связей вроде такой, Button -> GroupButton, Photo -> GalleryPhoto и т.д. Вот [примерчик](https://jsfiddle.net/ou9z7y1e/1/) набросал, по идее, при нажатии на зеленый квадрат, должно алертом вывести "ок", но этого почему-то не происходит, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Ну вы onClick никак в Button не обрабатываете... добавьте обработку и все ок... https://jsfiddle.net/ou9z7y1e/2/

Comment: Я добавил строку
onClick: this.props.onClick,

Comment: И такой момент, используйте jsx и ES6 фишки, многие моменты намного изящней станут. https://gist.github.com/alexesDev/3fe1ff7e67a0a7135c74ba673084551e

Comment: да я уже coffeescript использую, поддержка конечно не очень, но и отказываться тоже не хочется, вот еще думаю, перейти ли на babel или на coffee остаться

Comment: Я когда-то писал на кофе, но сейчас он скорее мертв. ES6\ES7 развивается семимильными шагами, нет смысла продолжать использовать кофе. Очень любил этот язык, но новые фишки JS переманили.

Comment: вот собственно согласен, умирает кофе с каждым днем все больше и больше, думаю да, лучше перейти на новый инструментарий :.)